# is the branch instruction data dependent?

Tags: assembly, pipeline, cpu-architecture

I have a sequence of instruction for a function followed by following two instructions

```
Loop: .
      .
      .
      .
SUB R20, R4, Rx
BNZ R20, Loop
```

Is BNZ, branch not zero data dependent on SUB instruction? or is it anti-dependency?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*In theory,* there exists a data-dependency between the branch instruction and the earlier instruction (the `SUB` in this case) that modifies the register the branch will examine to jump, but on many modern architectures this dependency does *not propagate* to the following instructions, unlike other data dependencies, due to branch prediction.

Instead, we say that the following instructions have a *control dependency* on the jump, and this control dependency behaves very differently than a data dependency.

That is, on architectures with prediction the data dependency isn't likely to actually cause the branch to *take effect* after the `SUB` - usually it will take effect (i.e., jump or not) before the `SUB` is executed, and only later when the result of the `SUB` is available will the guess be checked, and all the speculative execution since the branch will be rolled back if the guess was incorrect.

So in a way jumps exist in a grey area when it comes to data dependency on their condition and on their target. In the strictest sense they are dependent, but when prediction is working (and usually it is), they don't behave like that. It's a bit like the grey area that `xor r1, r1, r1` or `foo32bits >> 32` exist in: by the strict definition these instructions depend on their inputs, but in these particular case it happens that the answer is always the same (0) and some CPUs may recognize this and not apply the usual dependency rules.

Comment: Even if the jump is predicted and happens before the instruction, there still exists a data dependency. The comparison that eventually has to take place  to verify the prediction is still dependent on the SUB instruction.

Comment: @BenBurk: Yes, I think I made that clear. The branch basically executes in two phases - the with-prediction phase in the front-end/fetch, and then later again in the branch unit/ALU where it will actually execute. The latter half has a data dependency, but it doesn't really _matter_ for performance since the dependency can't be carried beyond that instruction.

Comment: The term you're looking for (or were in 2016) is "control dependency".  The instructions after the branch (or at the target if taken) have a control dependency on the branch condition, thus on the data tested by the branch.  The branch instruction itself just verifies the prediction made by the front-end, and has a data dependency on the input register (which is a general-purpose reg on RISC-V or MIPS, or is the flags register on most other ISAs).

Comment: @PeterCordes - yeah I should have used that term somewhere, I've added it now.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there exists a data dependency between the instructions. A branch instruction breaks down into a comparison and a jump. The comparison will be evaluated by the ALU, and then update the PC accordingly. The inputs to that comparison operation are dependent the same way any other operation would be.

Comment: Though, to be more specific, it's really operating on the flags register. That register can be modified by many instructions.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer Given the register operand in the BNZ, it's probably a MIPS-like architecture where there is no flags register, and the compare and branch instructions are combined into one.

Comment: It should be noted that in the presence of branch prediction, the jump will usually be the end of the dependency chain - no future instruction will depend on the `BNZ`. Without branch prediction, *all* subsequent instructions effectively depend on the branch, since it must be resolved to make forward progress, so branches can be part of a long (critical) dependency chain. With branch prediction, even though the `BNZ` is _in principle_ data dependent, the processor will guess at the result w/o waiting for the source data, effectively decoupling it, unless it guesses wrong.